# The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am new with C#. I am using Visual Studio 13, my problem is that it's throwing me this error:

> The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Yes, I added references from here https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki 
and I followed the tutorial from here : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0hL5sGkUSA

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace PercobaanDulu
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connString;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connString = @" Data Source = C:\Users\Febry Fairuz\Desktop\dbDemoLagi.db; Version = 3";
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connString)) {
                try { 
                    con.Open();
                    if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open){
                        MessageBox.Show("Koneksi berhasil dengan SQLite");
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Do the version of the .NET runtime match? Are you for example running a .NET 4 project while the referenced assemblies are 4.5?

Comment: i use version of the net 4.5

Comment: One thing you can do is remove all the SQLite relevant references from your project, fire up the Package Manager Console (Tools -> Nuget Package manager -> Package Manager Console) and type "Install-Package System.Data.SQLite". Nuget is smart enough to figure out what version of the library you need, based on your project settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are referencing incorrect version of `System.Data.Sqlite.dll` which is not compatible with version of .NET which you are using. You should check and install the compatible version of the dll to get rid of your problem.

If you are using the .Net 4.5 then you can try the NuGet package [System.Data.SQLite](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/).

A direct link for the package is [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe)

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by using

```
Visual Studio > Tools > NuGet Package manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution
```

Browse for "System.Data.sqlite" and install it for you project.
Do not install just SQLite. install System.Data.sqlite .